# The most efficient method to obtain the total entries into a mysql table

Tags: mysql, innodb, count

I have a table that has a very high usage (insert/update/select) - one of the operations is
to obtain a count of the number of rows.
So far I've been using the classic `select count(pk) from table` but I'm thinking to read it from information_schema instead of doing the count.

`select table_rows from tables where table_name = 'my_table'`

Is this reliable enough ?

If there is a different method please let me know.

thanks!

Comment: Is the table using MyISAM or InnoDB ???

Comment: the table is innodb

Answer (score 2):

If the table is MyISAM then you can

```
select table_rows from information_schema.tables
where table_schema='my_db' table_name = 'my_table';
```

or

```
select count(1) from my_db.my_table;
```

Either will work since the row count is physically stored in the `.MYD` file of the MyISAM table.

If the table is using InnoDB, the information_schema is absolutely no good for you because of the [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) and [transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) it supports.

What is even worse about InnoDB is terms of counting is the fact that mysqld will guess at the cardinality of a table (row count) by doing BTREE dives in the indexes.

To learn more about this InnoDB Counting phenomenon, please read my Apr 23, 2012 post : [Why is a secondary index chosen over a clustered index for SELECT COUNT(*) ...?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/why-is-a-secondary-index-chosen-over-a-clustered-index-for-select-count/16900#16900)