# Information schema not showing reliable information?

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

I'm currently migrating from SQL Server to MySQL. When i try to match the number of rows i query information_Schema.tables. I noticed that there are some differences between the migrated information and the source information.

However, I did a `select count(*) from table;` gave me the correct number of rows

Why is there a difference between the `information_Schema.tables.table_rows` and the `select count(*) from table`?

Comment: Are you running these queries from the information_schema? Where is that table called `table`? Can you prefix it with the schema name so that you know where the data is coming from?

Comment: Thank you Vérace they are in a schema called crmadmin.  So when i run the query: `select table_name,table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_schema='crmadmin' and table_name='table1';` and when i do `select count(*) from crmadmin.table1;` i get different results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause is the storage engine. InnoDB does not update the `information_schema.tables.table_rows` column.

I have old posts that explain this further

- `Apr 23, 2012` : [Why is a secondary index chosen over a clustered index for SELECT COUNT(*) ...?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/why-is-a-secondary-index-chosen-over-a-clustered-index-for-select-count/16900#16900)
- `May 16, 2012` : [Why doesn't InnoDB store the row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count/17992#17992)
- `Mar 03, 2014` : [The most efficient method to obtain the total entries into a mysql table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60053/the-most-efficient-method-to-obtain-the-total-entries-into-a-mysql-table/60065#60065)

You can get an approximation using `SHOW INDEXES FROM` against the table

If you would like to count all the tables in your current database regardless of the storage engine, just run this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024*1024*1024;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sqltocount SEPARATOR ' UNION ') sqlcount INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ''',table_name,''' tablename,COUNT(1) RowCount
FROM ',table_name) sqltocount FROM (SELECT table_name FROM
information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()) AA) A;
SELECT @sql\G PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rolando, his answer works fine. I also created a stored procedure to get that information, i'll post it if it's useful for somebody:

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysql.getRowCount;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysql.getRowCount(DBNAME VARCHAR(30))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE NO_DATA int default 0;
        DECLARE TBNAME varchar(30);
        DECLARE TBS CURSOR FOR select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=DBNAME;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET NO_DATA=1;
        OPEN TBS;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_count (table_schema varchar(30),table_name varchar(30),table_count varchar(11)) ENGINE=MEMORY;
        tbs:LOOP
            FETCH TBS into TBNAME;
            IF NO_DATA=1 THEN 
                LEAVE tbs;
            END IF;
            SET @query=concat('SELECT count(*) into @CONT from ',DBNAME,'.',TBNAME,';');
            PREPARE test FROM @query;
            EXECUTE test;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE test;
            SET @query=concat('INSERT into table_count values ("',DBNAME,'","',TBNAME,'","',@CONT,'");');
            PREPARE test FROM @query;
            EXECUTE test;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE test;
        END LOOP tbs;
        CLOSE TBS;
        SELECT * from table_count;
        DROP TABLE table_count;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
call mysql.getRowCount('mysql');`